# Data not decrypting correctly - data from csv

Tags: python, pandas, encryption, encoding, aes

My input ciphertext from my csv doesnt seem to be decrypting properly. It decrypts as a random string of bytes. I've checked my key and IV and they are exactly the same from encryption, Its just the decryption that doesnt seem to work properly.

I wondered if the way I have put my encrypted data into my csv, or retrieved it is the issue? maybe it alters the bytes etc? if not im stumped. I've been on this issue for days, help!

Program works like this:

User inputs credentials -- encrypt -- generate unique ID and hash values and stores in db -- store ciphertext in csv // user inputs ID -- matches in db and fetches encryption key stored with ID -- Fetches matching ID ciphertext from CSV, puts into pandas dataframe and decrypts ciphertext with key

```
def decoder():
    from Crypto.Cipher import AES
    import hashlib
    from secrets import token_bytes

    cursor.execute(
        '''
        Select enc_key FROM Login where ID = (?);
        ''',
        (L_ID_entry.get(), ))

    row = cursor.fetchone()
    if row is not None:
        keys = row[0]

        #design padding function for encryption
        def padded_text(data_in):
            while len(data_in)% 16 != 0:
                data_in = data_in + b"0"
            return data_in

        #calling stored key from main file and reverting back to bytes
        key_original = keys
        print(key_original)
        print("Key original above")
        mode = AES.MODE_CBC

        #model
        cipher = AES.new(key_original, mode, IV2.encode('utf8'))
        print(IV2)
        print("IV2 above")

        #padding data
        p4 = padded_text(df1.tobytes())
        p5 = padded_text(df2.tobytes())
        p6 = padded_text(df3.tobytes())

        #decrypting data
        d_fname = cipher.decrypt(p4)
        d_sname = cipher.decrypt(p5)
        d_email = cipher.decrypt(p6)

        print(d_fname)
        print(d_sname)
        print(d_email)

#connecting to db
try:
    conn = sqlite3.connect('login_details.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    print("Connected to SQLite")

except sqlite3.Error as error:
    print("Failure, error: ", error)
finally:
    #downloading txt from dropbox and converting to dataframe to operate on
    import New_user
    import ast
    _, res = client.files_download("/user_details/enc_logins.csv")
    with io.BytesIO(res.content) as csvfile:
        with open("enc_logins.csv", 'rb'):
            df = pd.read_csv(csvfile,  names=['ID', 'Fname', 'Sname', 'Email'], encoding='utf-8')
            newdf = df[df['ID'] == L_ID_entry.get()]
            print(newdf)
            df1 = newdf['Fname'].values
            df2 = newdf['Sname'].values
            df3 = newdf['Email'].values
            print(df1)
            print(df2)
            print(df3)

    decoder()
```

Comment: Why are you padding prior to decrypt ? Padding is added prior to encrypt, and removed after decrypt.

Comment: I did think that may be the issue. But when I remove padding it states that the data isn't in 16byte format as required for AES encryption. So somewhere along the way my data must be changing from the 16byte padded format as of the original encryption. im really not sure what would be causing it to change like that.